# Trying to place avatar on every page in PHPbb Forum. Only showing up in index page... any ideas?

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3, avatar

The website that im trying to make it work on is http://www.phone7forum.com/

The way I get it to show up on the index page is adding this code to the core index.php page right below this:

```
// Assign index specific vars
'S_AVATAR' => get_user_avatar(
    $user->data['user_avatar'],
    $user->data['user_avatar_type'],
    $user->data['user_avatar_width'],
    $user->data['user_avatar_height']
),
```

Then I can use {S_AVATAR} in my template but it ONLY shows up in the index file... So another phpbb guy suggested that I take that same code from above and place it in the includes/functions.php file right below this:

```
// The following assigns all _common_ variables that may be used at any point in a template.
```

I did that, and though it seemed to "try" and work I clicked on a few pages outside the index page and got a fatal error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_user_avatar() in /home/content/04/6534704/html/phone7forum/includes/functions.php on line 4385

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your site, BTW, looks good. Did you do it all yourself? I am a noobie at it, and can't figure out some of the basics.

Answer (score 1):

`IIRC get_user_avatar()` is a function from `functions_display`. If you want to use it in the functions file, you have to include it.

Put it into an if condition to have it only load if you're on a page where `function_display` isn't already included:

```
if(!function_exists('get_user_avatar')){ include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx); }
```